# When is tomorrow?

Tags: hearthstone

I've completed all my daily quests for Hearthstone, and I'm now seeing a message telling me to come back tomorrow.

[image: Image that says "You have no quests. Check back tomorrow!"]

When is tomorrow exactly? I don't see any sort of countdown to be able to tell which timezone is being used as a baseline, nor whether daylight savings time is in effect.

Comment: Based on cultural knowledge gleaned from musical films in my youth in the early 80's, I was taught that tomorrow is just a day away.

Answer (score 5):

You can read about it here: http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Quest

> After 10am Pacific time each day (previously 2am Pacific), players are awarded one new quest, known as a daily quest, or 'daily'.

But my personal observation at Europe server doesn't agree with it. New quests always appear at night, which is between 14 and 22 o'clock PST. Mostly about 17 PST I believe, but I noted that each day the time can be different.

Comment: In Europe, I always get a daily quest at 01:00 CET give or take a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

tommorow for europe usually happens around 00:00 GMT - 01:00 GMT, depending on how long it takes for the queue daemon to process your account (they have a few million accounts at least, if they didn't hit the 10mil mark already)

Answer (score 0):

Tomorrow for Hearthstone is the American time in California. The Blizzard studios are based there.

Comment: And when is tommorow in california?) Now 10:30 PM there, but I have got a new quest, which wasn't there at 13:30 PM in california.

Answer (score 0):

Blizzard servers are located in California (as @xXEaterofSoulsXx pointed out), which is the PST (Pacific Standard Time). This is ~7 hours behind GMT (Greenwich Mean Time).

So depending on where you are in the world, this should hopefully help you determine at what time of the day "Tomorrow" is for you.

Comment: California is Pacific (PST/PDT) time, not Eastern time.